# How to ask Conan to install mingw automatically?

Tags: conan

In Windows 11 I have no compiler, no [Ninja](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja).

I have already installed Conan and Cmake 3.27.7

```
pip install conan
pip install cmake
```

I want to repeat a very simple [example](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/use_tools_as_conan_packages.html) but I make it even simpler; `main.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
ninja/1.11.1
mingw-builds/12.2.0

[tool_requires]
cmake/3.22.6

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

My steps:

```
examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires> conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing
```

Log:

> ======== Input profiles ======== Profile host: [settings] arch=x86_64 build_type=Release os=Windows
>
> Profile build: [settings] arch=x86_64 build_type=Release os=Windows
>
> ======== Computing dependency graph ======== Graph root
> conanfile.txt: C:\Users\Dunge\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires\conanfile.txt
> Requirements
> mingw-builds/12.2.0#6d4f9fa696c4097c55762e2f481a2355 - Cache
> ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21 - Cache Build requirements
> 7zip/19.00#225017a375b8ed37d07d6623e85d9332 - Cache
> cmake/3.22.6#32cced101c6df0fab43e8d00bd2483eb - Cache
> lzma_sdk/9.20#f1fe20056422603432563a07b25f2ee3 - Cache
> make/4.3#f3747ef6e47bbd049f9f3f14a9e1d8ba - Cache
> msys2/cci.latest#567331f1604f3c584f04feade960f06e - Cache
>
> ======== Computing necessary packages ======== Requirements
> mingw-builds/12.2.0#6d4f9fa696c4097c55762e2f481a2355:f4943bfd33cc2961ebbb1d81bf8b090153522e1f#5f5a8fabb19ee4c50cd60cea4f4d5237
>
> - Cache
>   ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21:723257509aee8a72faf021920c2874abc738e029#74ebd8f35f54015dcbf2b18a6adbd023
> - Cache Build requirements
>   cmake/3.22.6#32cced101c6df0fab43e8d00bd2483eb:522dcea5982a3f8a5b624c16477e47195da2f84f#a9d024f459972755e5a815b775408fff
> - Cache Skipped binaries
>   7zip/19.00, lzma_sdk/9.20, make/4.3, msys2/cci.latest
>
> ======== Installing packages ======== cmake/3.22.6: Already installed! (1 of 3) cmake/3.22.6: Appending PATH environment variable:
> C:\Users\Dunge.conan2\p\cmake1927748c2604b\p\bin ninja/1.11.1:
> Already installed! (2 of 3) mingw-builds/12.2.0: Already installed! (3
> of 3) WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that
> will be removed in Conan 2.X: WARN: deprecated:     'env_info' used
> in: cmake/3.22.6, mingw-builds/12.2.0
>
> ======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ======== conanfile.txt: Writing generators to
> C:\Users\Dunge\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires\build
> conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
> conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
> conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
> conanfile.txt: Preset 'conan-release' added to CMakePresets.json.
> Invoke it manually using 'cmake --preset conan-release' if using
> CMake>=3.23 conanfile.txt: If your CMake version is not compatible
> with CMakePresets (<3.23) call cmake like: 'cmake  -G "MinGW
> Makefiles"
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Dunge\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires\build\conan_toolchain.cmake
> -DCMAKE_SH=CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: CMakePresets.json conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated:
> ..\CMakeUserPresets.json conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env
> files conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files:
> ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat'] Install finished successfully

```
examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires> cd build
examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires> ./conanbuild.bat
examples2\tutorial\consuming_packages\tool_requires> cmake -S .. -B . -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE='conan_toolchain.cmake' --fresh
```

Log

> -- Using Conan toolchain: C:/Users/Dunge/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/examples2/tutorial/consuming_packages/tool_requires/build/conan_toolchain.cmake
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the
> environment   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER
> to the full path to   the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is
> in the PATH.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Why can't Conan install MinGW with Ninja by himself and use it by himself?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `ninja` and `mingw` should be `tool_requires` rather than requires.  I just tried this (on Windows 10) and it worked for me (and used the correct compiler: MINGW 12.2.0).

mainfile.c:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.3)

project(simple)
enable_language(C)

set(C_SOURCE_FILES
    mainfile.c
    )

set(EXECUTABLE ${PROJECT_NAME})
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE} ${C_SOURCE_FILES} )
```

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]

[tool_requires]
cmake/3.22.6
mingw-builds/12.2.0
ninja/1.11.1

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

Commands run at the shell

```
python -m pip install conan

# This found MSVC on my system, but it isn't used later:
conan profile detect --force

conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing

cd build

.\conanbuild.bat

cmake -G Ninja ..

cmake --build .

.\simple.exe
```